# Comando if-else não está funcionando

Tags: c, if, operadores

Em um dos exercícios de um livro que estou lendo, é pedido para que eu trace o "perfil" de uma pessoa de acordo com o ano em que ela nasceu (como aqueles testes de Facebook) mas no intuito de limitar a possibilidade do que for digitado, coloquei um `if` para sinalizar um erro, mas mesmo com o valor dando positivo para o `if`, o bloco do `else` segue executando, como posso resolver?

```
int main(void){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    int y,a,b,c;
    printf("Digite seu ano de nascimento (quatro digitos)\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    if (y>9999 && y<1000) printf("Ano inválido");
        else {
        b=y%100;
        a=y/100;
        c=a+b;
        c=c%5;
        switch(c){
            case 0:printf("Tímido\n"); break;
            case 1:printf("Sonhador\n"); break;
            case 2:printf("Paquerador\n"); break;
            case 3:printf("Atraente\n"); break;
            case 4:printf("Irresistível\n"); break;
                }
            }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Qual é seu problema?

Comment: mesmo colocando um ano como 20000 ou 3, ainda é dado um resultado do bloco de else

Comment: não entendi, mas na pergunta foram cortadas algumas palavras do que coloquei, por isso ficou dificil de entender

Comment: @motorola Se tá falando da minha edição, eu não removi nada de mais. Você pode confirmar isso no histórico.

Comment: não foi da tua edição, realmente algumas palavras que coloquei na pergunta na apareceram

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Esta linha

```
if (y>9999 && y<1000) printf("Ano inválido");
```

diz: Se Y é maior que 9999 E menor que 1000 imprima "Ano inválido"

Esta condição é sempre falsa. Ou seja, o `else` SEMPRE é executado.

Tente assim:

```
if (y>9999 || y<1000) printf("Ano inválido");
```

Answer (score 2):

A comparação está usando um *and* `&&` quando o correto seria um *or* `||`, já que é inválido tanto um quanto o outro. Na verdade seria impossível ambos serem inválidos, porque **ou ** o número é maior que 9999 ou ele é menor que 1000, não tem como um número ser os dois ao mesmo tempo, que é uma exigência do *and*.

Dei uma melhorada, mas poderia melhorar mais, poderia dar nomes melhores para as variáveis e até eliminar algumas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int y = 0;
    printf("Digite seu ano de nascimento (quatro digitos)\n");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    if (y > 9999 || y < 1000) { 
        printf("Ano inválido");
    } else {
        int b = y % 100;
        int a = y / 100;
        int c = a + b;
        c %= 5;
        switch (c) {
            case 0: printf("Tímido\n"); break;
            case 1: printf("Sonhador\n"); break;
            case 2: printf("Paquerador\n"); break;
            case 3: printf("Atraente\n"); break;
            case 4: printf("Irresistível\n"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/4fXBv0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/acriuslz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/AndOr.c).